# Using Visual Studio MSDN

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Used Visual C++ 6.0 in the past, there was also a support library for MSDN, directory of all errors, etc. Is there a comparable software module to the MSDN package for Visual Studio 2019? Sid Kraft

Comment: FWIW, if it's core C++, or the standard library, you can't really beat [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for a lookup of what things are and how to use them.  As far as errors go, they should be detailed in the build pane

Comment: F1 brings context-sensitive online help.

Comment: MSDN / online docs are a lot more accessible now than back in those days. For a long time now I've found I can just google "MSDN" followed by the thing I want to know about and end up with their documentation on it.

Comment: You can [install the help contents locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/help-viewer/install-manage-local-content?view=vs-2019), which is largely on par with the old MSDN, and even looks very much like it.

Comment: Like @TheUndeadFish I just google it now. I have not missed the MSDN local install in 10+ years.

Answer (score 1):

You could install `Help Viewer` in `Visual Studio Installer->Individual Components`

[image]

Then, you could download `MSDN Docs` what you want in `Help->Add and Remove Help Content`.